# Ubuntu 18.04 iso without desktop environment

Tags: 18.04, desktop-environments

I was wondering if anyone knows any link to an iso of 18.04 Desktop (not server) without a desktop environment. Sure i could install ubuntu and uninstall the desktop environment, but that would be too much work.

Comment: Desktop "without a desktop environment" is a server. :-))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the mini iso.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

It basically includes nothing except the base system by default, you have to specify all packages to install.  If you don't want a desktop, simply don't install one.

[image]